# Splash screen block Ionic on iOS

Tags: angular, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm facing some problems during the installation of my Ionic app on iOS. This is my list of plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 2.1.1 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 3.3.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
```

The problem is that after the installation the iOS is blocked on the splash screen page and it can't move on. Where am I wrong?

To build the app is run the command `ionic cordova prepare ios` and then the build button in Xcode.

This is the output the console:

```
NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
```

Comment: Open Safari and debug your application and see if you got any error.

Comment: with ionic serve no error in Safari

Comment: not with `ionic serve` make build with Xcode and connect your device via cable and debug it. same as Android with Chrome.